# Finding mean and covariance of an arbitrary joint pdf

Tags: probability, distributions, mean, density-function, covariance

Let's say that I have the following joint pdf, defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{54.4366}\exp(\frac{-x^2}{200}-\frac{1}{2}(y+0.05x^{2}-5)^2)$

How would I go about calculating the mean and covariance matrix associated with this pdf?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You sure that it is $0.05x^2$ in the exponent and not $0.05x$? The problem is relatively straightforward if it is $0.05x$. That $0.05x^2$ makes it much messier.

Comment: Unfortunately it is $0.05x^2$ in the exponent. Despite this, how would I go about finding the mean and covariance?

Comment: I believe that 54.4366 should be $20\pi \simeq 62.8319$ for $f(x,y)$ to be a joint pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jim Baldwin mentioned in the comments, your expression for the joint PDF doesn't integrate to 1, so it isn't a valid probability distribution. I'll assume the normalizing constant is $20 \pi$ instead of 54.366, which gives a valid distribution.

**Joint distribution**

$$f_{XY}(x, y) =
\frac{1}{20 \pi}
\exp \left (
    -\frac{x^2}{200} - \frac{1}{2} (y + 0.05 x^2-5)^2
\right )$$

This distribution also has a convenient form when expressed as the product of the marginal distribution of $X$ and the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$:

$$f_{XY}(x, y) = f_X(x) \ f_{Y \mid X}(x, y)$$

$f_{X}$ is Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 100 (as shown below), and $f_{Y \mid X}$ is Gaussian with mean $5-\frac{x^2}{20}$ and variance 1 (which can be shown by dividing $f_{XY}$ by $f_{X}$).

[image]

$f_{XY}$ has a narrow, parabolic shape, so the mean and covariance matrix won't do a great job of summarizing it. But, they can be computed as follows.

**Mean**

The mean is $[\mu_x, \mu_y]$, where $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are the expected values of the marginal distributions.

The marginal distribution of $X$ can be found by integrating out $Y$:

$$f_X(x)
= \int_{=\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(x, y) dy
= \frac{1}{10 \sqrt{2 \pi}}
\exp \left ( -\frac{x^2}{200} \right )$$

This is a Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 100, so $\mu_X = 0$.

Similarly, $\mu_Y$ can be found by integrating out $X$, then taking the expected value:

$$f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(x, y) dx$$

$$\mu_y = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \ f_Y(y) dy$$

I couldn't find closed form expressions, but the integrals can be computed [numerically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) using standard software. This typically requires specifying finite integration bounds. You can use bounds at which the density tapers to negligibly small values (check that the distribution integrates numerically to ~1 over your chosen bounds).

**Covariance**

The covariance matrix is:

$$\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
    \sigma_{X}^2 & \sigma_{XY}^2 \\
    \sigma_{XY}^2 & \sigma_{Y}^2 \\
\end{array} \right ]$$

where $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ are the variances of $X$ and $Y$, and $\sigma_{XY}^2$ is the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. As shown above, $X$ has variance 100.

$\sigma_Y^2$ can be computed (again using numerical integration) as:

$$\sigma_Y^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (y-\mu_y)^2 f_Y(y) dy$$

For $\sigma_{XY}^2$, we can use the following relationship:

$$\text{cov}(X, Y) = E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$

Therefore:

$$\sigma_{XY}^2 = E[XY] - \mu_X \mu_Y$$

All that remains is to calculate $E[XY]$ which can be done in closed form:

$$E[XY]
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x y \ f_{XY}(x, y) dx dy
= 0$$

Therefore, $\sigma_{XY}^2 = 0$. This makes sense, looking at the symmetry of the joint distribution about the y axis.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, this makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @user20160 's answer, here is some *Mathematica* code to perform the calculations.  (And it does not appear that the mean and variance of $y$ can be given in a closed form hence the numerical integration below.)

```
(* Check that things integrate to 1 *)
Integrate[Exp[-x^2/200 - (1/2) (y + x^2/20 - 5)^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]/(20 Pi)
(* 1 *)

(* Marginal distribution of x *)
fx = Integrate[f[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* \[ExponentialE]^(-(x^2/200))/(10 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) *)

(* Mean of x *)
xMean = Integrate[x Integrate[f[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* 0 *)

(* Variance of x *)
xVariance = Integrate[x^2 Integrate[f[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - xMean^2
(* 100 *)

(* Marginal density of y is fy1 if y < 49/10 and fy2 if y > 49/10 *)
fy1 = Integrate[E^(-(x^2/200) - 1/2 (-5 + x^2/20 + y)^2)/(20 \[Pi]),
       {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> y < 49/10]
fy2 = Integrate[E^(-(x^2/200) - 1/2 (-5 + x^2/20 + y)^2)/(20 \[Pi]), 
       {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> y >= 49/10]
(* Density of y at y = 49/10 *)
Limit[fy2, y -> 49/10]
(* Gamma[1/4]/(2 2^(3/4) Sqrt[5] \[ExponentialE]^(1/200) \[Pi]) *)

(* Mean of y *)
yMean = NIntegrate[y fy1, {y, -30, 49/10}] + NIntegrate[y fy2, {y, 49/10, 15}]
(* 0.3207576948514401 *)

(* Variance of y *)
yVariance = NIntegrate[y^2 fy1, {y, -30, 49/10}] + NIntegrate[y^2  fy2, {y, 49/10, 15}] - yMean^2
(* 37.65761182719062 *)

(* Covariance of x and y *)
cov = Integrate[x y f[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* 0 *)
```

[image: Formula for density of y]

where $I_n (x)$ and $K_n (x)$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively.

[image: Figure of density of y]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I admit it is a rather messy distribution to be working with!